# Getting password from forms login with MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, forms, authentication, passwords

I'm using the MVC forms log in which works ok, but I need to call a data service which requires the same Username and Password combination from within a controller.

Using HttpContext.User.Identity.Name I can get the name, but what about the password? Is there any way to retrieve this after the user has already logged in?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you shouldn't be storing passwords in your application. Membership provider doesn't store the password in clear-text anywhere. All you have in database is **salted hash**. There is no way to obtain user's password after they logged in.

You would need to get the password from the *Login* action or create a custom `MembershipProvider`.

But consider changing the design if possible so you don't have to keep clear-text passwords. Once the user has been authenticated you know who it is, and lower layers in your application can trust upper layers with passing the authenticated principal to them. Otherwise why would they trust with passing correct username/password pair?

Comment: Thanks, I suspected this might me the case. I've tried storing it in a session state, but the session states are far from aligned with the forms login. Often the sessions drop out where the user is still authenticated.

Comment: If you don't want ASP.NET to create new session on each request try adding some dummy value to `Session`: `Session["dummy"] = 1`.

Comment: Thanks Jakub. This was getting messy, so I used a whole different approach. I needed the password to get a value Provider from a data service. Instead I combined the Username and Provider in the LogOnModel, so by splitting the username string I can also get the Provider, and I don't have to worry about any session stuff. This is an infinitely better solution. Cheers.